# The argument of pthread function can be another function?

Tags: c, pthreads

I know how to pass a function as an argument for another function. But I don't know if the argument of a function passed to pthread can be another function. Is this even possible?

Here is sample code that compiles OK, but doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_t idThread;

void aFunction(){
    while(1){
        fprintf(stderr,"I've been called!\n");
        usleep(1000000);
    }
}

void * threadFunction(void *argFunc){
    // Do here some stuff;
    // ...

    // Now call the function passed as argument
    void (*func)() = argFunc;
}    

int thread_creator(void(*f)()){
    // I want to use as argument for threadFunction the f function
    pthread_create(&idThread, NULL, threadFUnction, (void *)f);
}

int main(){
    thread_creator(aFunction);
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to call your function. (`func()`)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be a function pointer, if you're willing to bend rules a little. Strictly speaking a `void *` isn't guaranteed to be able to hold a function pointer. Something like this (untested):

```
void some_fun()
{
    /* ... */
}

void thread_fun(void *arg)
{
    void (*fun)() = arg;
}

pthread_create(...., (void *) some_fun);
```

#### EDIT

In your example, you also need to call the function, via the function pointer. Something like:

```
void (*func)() = argFunc;
funct(); /* <-- */
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, with your help my code compiles, but it doesn't work. I've added a sample code. Any idea?

Comment: POSIX requires that `void *` and function pointer types have the same size and representation, and that the cast in either direction be value-preserving. This requirement is imposed as a result of the way the mandatory `dlsym` interface works. So since POSIX threads are part of POSIX, this solution is completely portable within that framework.

Comment: Source: XSH 2.12.3 Pointer Types: *All function pointer types shall have the same representation as the type pointer to void. Conversion of a function pointer to void * shall not alter the representation. A void * value resulting from such a conversion can be converted back to the original function pointer type, using an explicit cast, without loss of information.* And the corresponding note: *The ISO C standard does not require this, but it is required for POSIX conformance.*

Comment: @R.. Pure awesomeness. Thanks for the quote!

Answer (score 3):

Stricly speaking, it is not possible. According to the standard, a pointer to `void` may just be converted to or from a  pointer to an object type. On some architectures, function adresses are larger than object adresses.

> **C11, § 6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object
>   type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to
>   `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original
>   pointer.

Otherwise, it is a common extension.

> **C11, § J.5.7 Function pointer casts**
>
> A pointer to an object or to `void` may be cast to a pointer to a
>   function, allowing data to be invoked as a function (6.5.4).

In your example, you don't call `func`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_t idThread;

void aFunction(void)
{
    while (1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "I've been called!\n");
        usleep(1000000);
    }
}

void *threadFunction(void *argFunc)
{
    void (*func)(void) = argFunc;
    func(); /* HERE */
}

int thread_creator(void (*f)(void))
{
    pthread_create(&idThread, NULL, threadFUnction, (void *) f);
}

int main(void)
{
    thread_creator(aFunction);
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Except since OP is using POSIX threads, OP also has the requirements of POSIX, and they guarantee it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answers already given:

Conceptually, function pointers can be passed around just like any other type of pointer, but - as has been pointed out - a `void *` is not guaranteed to be large enough to hold a function pointer, only a data pointer.

A workaround for something like the `pthread_create` callback function is to wrap your desired function pointer in a structure that you use as the user data:

```
struct threadArg
{
    void (*callback)(void);
};

// ...
struct threadArg *threadArg = malloc(sizeof(threadArg));
threadArg->callback = myFunction;
pthread_create(&idThread, NULL, threadFunction, (void *) threadArg);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for dubious casts involving function pointers.  The argument to the thread can be a pointer to a struct which can contain anything.

```
#include <pthread.h>

struct arg {
    void (*func)(void);
    int other_stuff;
};

void function(void)
{

}

void *thread_function(void *arg)
{
    struct arg *a1 = arg;

    a1->func();

    return NULL;
}


int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid;

    struct arg arg = {.func = function};

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_function, &arg);
    .
    .
    .

}
```

Comment: This is dangerous, as the thread_function might not run until after `main` has freed up its stack frame as part of returning, so the struct seen in `thread_function` might be garbage...

Comment: better `pthread_join` if you're gonna pass the new thread an automatic variable.

Comment: @ChrisDodd This code was just meant to illustrate how to pass arbitrary data to a thread during thread creation.